# Linearity of system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, chaos-theory

I am learning how to solve differential equations (ordinary and partial)and why they are so important for physics.One thing I have noticed so far is that we know so little on the nature of the solutions of a differential equation , only very few forms of differential equations are solvable and even less forms of systems of differential equations are solvable.

I have always wondered.Small changes in the starting conditions of a system cause big changes only if the system isnt linear.Can small changes in the coefficients of the terms of a system of differential equations cause huge changes in the solution?Is there any related research going on?

Comment: Your question is interesting but too broad. The short answer is yes, but it really depends on a lot of factors. If you want to learn more, read some books related to Mathematical Physics. Differential equations are about the rate of change and if you look around, not many things are static in this world. Even our galaxy is moving.

Comment: Even for a linear differential equation, small changes in the initial conditions can cause big changes eventually.  Try $dx/dt = x$ and compare initial conditions $x(0) = 0$, $x(0) = \epsilon$ and $x(0) = -\epsilon$.

Comment: There is perturbation theory where small changes in the equation produce, over fixed time intervals, small changes in the solution. And the other extreme of singular perturbation, where a small change in the leading order coefficient produces short phases of rapid changes.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I have never used analytical solution of differential equations in practice or at least for engineering application. As you pointed out, only the simplest problems have known solutions and these are nowhere near the complex problems we face in real world.

Most of the time, engineers resort to empirical or numerical solutions. Empirical solutions come from experiments and numerical solutions are obtained through simulations such as Finite Element Method (FEM), Finite Volume Method (FVM), etc.. As my mentor told me, if we waited for analytical solutions, we wouldn't have airplanes for another couple of centuries.

As for your question, there are plenty of researches in that field e.g. sensitivity analysis, stochastic model, etc.. For example, one may study how much change in structural beam's thickness (related to coefficient of DE) affect overal structure's thickness.